# How to download MEDLINE text file from NCBI PubMed using python script?

Tags: python, web-scraping, ncbi, pubmed

I want to download a MEDLINE file from [NCBI PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) using python script.
These are the steps I want to achieve. Go to the link provided [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) and search "Gene Editing". Then click on "Send to" and choose "File" and change the format to "MEDLINE" and click Create File, which downloads the file. I want to automate this entire process using python script.
I tried Beautiful Soup. I am able to get the text from the page, but I don't know how to click an choose different options.
This is the code I have written so far..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=gene+editing"
page = requests.get(url).text
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [tour]. On SO, questions should reflect what you tried so far to resolve your problem and ideally include a minimum working example of code you came up with so far.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.